# Why g.V() in gremlin is a GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex>?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

g.V() is usually used to start a traversal. But since this a startup action, why its begin node is a Vertex?

Answer (score 3):

`g` is the `TraversalSource`, by specifying `V()` you're saying that you are going to start at a set of elements that are of type `Vertex`, just like by specifying `E()` would specify starting at a set of elements that are of type `Edge` http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#the-graph-process and http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#traversal are pretty clear on how traversals are built up.